# Is there a way of knowing if a Django server is running in DEBUG mode?

Tags: apache-http-server, python, webserver, nginx, django

Given a third party project running Django on a cloud platform behind NGINX or Apache, is there a way of knowing:

1. the project is indeed using Django as a framework
2. whether DEBUG is set to `True` or `False`

For example, a way of knowing if DEBUG is `True` would be to find an error page (404 or 500 for example) and see if the DEBUG UI shows - provided the error page is not overwritten with a custom page.

Is there another, more reliable way to know for sure the status of `DEBUG`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way is to just check in Python:

```python
from django.conf import settings


if settings.DEBUG is True:
    [...]
```

Comment: I want to know if a third party server is running Django. I don't have access to the code - that would be very easy otherwise.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. I think a 404 is the best way to check.

Comment: It is possible that a custom 404 page is being used, in which case the debug info does not show.